# SOLR Streaming VS Search

Tags: solr, lucene

What are the key differences between streaming and normal search in terms of internal implementation . A normal search would also work in a distributed manner , right ? How does streaming improve performance ? The documentation is not helping out .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distributed search issues requests, calculates results, delivers results and handles merging. Each step is processed fully before continuing to the next step. This works well enough when the amount of data is small. For larger requests, such as delivering millions of documents, this requires huge memory buffers. It also means that the caller has to wait until the very last step (delivery of the result to the caller) before the result can be processed.

With streaming, all this is ongoing: Calculation, delivery and merging happens at the same time, with a fixed upper memory overhead. You can ask for 10K results or you can ask for 10 billion, the only difference is how long it takes. As every part of the process is active at the same time, including delivery to the caller, this also means that the first result data will be delivered to the caller very quickly.

Internally, streaming is basically paging through the search result. Each page (10K documents, if I remember correctly) is passed along to the stream as soon as it has been calculated. Ignoring optimizations, the same behaviour could be emulated from the outside with deep paging and a custom merger.

Comment: Hello can you please elaborate with a simple query , and explain how streaming performs well over search

Comment: `q=*:*&rows=100000000` on an index with 100M documents, is a near-sure way of blowing your heap, no matter if your setup is distributed or not. First example on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Streaming+Expressions has no such problem.

Comment: So the issue here is for loading all 1M docs at once , wherein streaming lets you get one doc at a time in client side , right , What if i would need to do some computation over these 1M docs , still i would need to hold these 1M docs in memory (obtained via streaming) , right ?

Comment: What you do in the client is your responsibility and is dictated by the task you want to achieve. Even if you need to hold the full result in memory at the client, streaming from Solr can be beneficial for the Solr nodes.

Comment: Does that mean less load on the SOLR nodes if i stream through ?

Comment: If you request very large result sets, then (mostly) yes: The memory load will be a lot less and the CPU load will less due to simpler garbage collection (fewer and shorter lived objects at a time).